# Coffee Table Photography Book

Tags: books, photographer

I am thinking of getting a small gift for my friend, preferably a small / medium size Photography Book (that can put on the coffee table) or for guests to boserse through - casual reading. My budget is less than US$50. The photography book can be a combination of works by several photographers or maybe a theme / just one famous photographer.

Are there any "classic goodies" out there?

please free to drop any comments

Comment: I've converted this to community wiki, as there isn't really a correct answer here, and it will ultimately just be a list of recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

**Wide Angle: National Geographic Greatest Places**

**Through the Lens: National Geographic Greatest Photographs**

Both these books have **504 pages** of absolutely stunning photographs. They have a mix of styles that reflect the magazines different photographers and times. I own both, among many others, but these two are my favorites. For what the cost, both these books are a fantastic bargain.

The photographs from National Geographic almost all have a lot of depth to them, which makes looking at each photo quite interesting. I went through each of these several times and seem to often notice new details.

Answer (score 3):

- 'The Americans' by Robert Frank
- 'Workers' by Sebastiao Salgado
- 'Portraits' by Steve McCurry
- '400 Photographs' by Ansel Adams

The list goes on and on.

Comment: +1 though I'm not sure 'Workers' or 'The Americans', while seminal works, might fit the coffee-table light chitchat bill. Depends on your friends I guess ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"The Photo Book" published by phaidon is a great collection 500 photos from the worlds mst famous photographers. It's a great book to flip through. The hardcover edition has become a bit if a collectors piece so you might have trouble getting it for you budget. The paperback is cheap but not exactly a coffee table book.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Vanity Fair portraits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0810972980) book for my coffee table.